# How to create the above custom clipPath widget? (I attached the screenshot)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-clippath

**Here is the custom Appbar I'm trying to archive**

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... Interesting...
If you want the cleanest solution possible, I would use something like `CustomPaint`, here you can take a look: [CustomPaint Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kp14Y4uHpHs)

But if that is not much of a deal, you can simply add PNG image with a shape you need (and a transparency in a place where u have custom shape). You can try standard `Image.asset()` and reshape it with something.

Also you can add a container at the bottom that, is 'cutting' the part of the app bar that you don't need. You can get it `BoxDecoration`, `BoxBorder.only` ... `topleft`, rounded rectangle ... and something like that.